# Scrollable List in Java

Tags: java, list

It may not be an appropriate term - scrollable but by scrollable, I mean a fixed size `java.util.List` with a different perspective.

The List should have defined number elements (predefined size). If an attempt is made to add more elements than the defined size, then those elements should be added with the removal of the top most elements in the List.

For example, let's say that the List has a predefined size of 5 elements and it already contains those many elements like the following (assuming the List is a generic type of String),

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Now, if an additional element `F` is added, then the element at the top (`A`) should be scrolled up and vanished. The List should now have the following elements.

```
B
C
D
E
F
```

Similarly, if `G` is added, then it should contain the following elements.

```
C
D
E
F
G
```

Removing the top most element `B` and so on.

Is there a fair way to do this? Is there any library that may support this kind of functionality?

BTW, the structure is not necessarily only a `java.util.List`. It can be anything, starting from arrays but since I need this in a web application, components provided by swing like `JList`, `JScrollPane` cannot be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a FIFO Data Structure like [Queue.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

You can write your own implementation to keep it at a fixed size like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12704325/2239110) or write a wrapper for an existing implementation like [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: Hi, the first link is broken.

Comment: Hi, all links are working fine for me ? The first one links to the JavaDocs of the Queue interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: Initially, my browser didn't respond. Now they all are working fine, sorry.

Comment: No problem. You could also write a wrapper for an existing implementation of Queue to keep at a fixed size.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Object> s = new ArrayList<>();
//Assuming the list has been populated
s.remove(0);
s.add(newObject);
```

This removes the element at index 0, then adds an element to the end of the `ArrayList`, giving you your desired result.

Comment: I found `LinkedList` and `Queue` more comfortable. Therefore, I have accepted Jim's answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Tiny That's reasonable. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a FIFO queue.
Java has a `Queue<E>` interface [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), `LinkedList` implements it: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).
You can add the elements with the `offer` method and remove elements (from the other end, it's a FIFO) with `remove` or `poll` calls.
You can see other implementations, you can specify capacity too.
I don't advise you to write your own if there's an available one which fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[**LinkedList**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) will resolves your issues which is an implementation of `FIFO Queue`.

More over its **faster** than `List`(operations).

> The class implements the Queue interface, providing first-in-first-out queue operations for add, poll, etc. Other stack and deque operations could be easily recast in terms of the standard list operations. They're included here primarily for convenience, though they may run slightly faster than the equivalent List operations

Comment: You cannot say that a `LinkedList` is faster than a `List`. A `List` is not an implementation. That's like saying that a BMW X6 M is faster than a car.

Comment: @Alderath I hope list means List operations.Sorry for the half bake.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, you are describing a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).  None of Java's collection classes directly implement a circular buffer, as the other answers suggest, you can imitate the functionality fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any library that support that functionality.
But you can make a simple method just to do exactly what you want.
I've done it myself and it's pretty straight forward though.

```
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList();
    int maxSize = 5;

    myList.add("A");
    myList.add("B");
    myList.add("C");
    myList.add("D");
    myList.add("E");

    int listSize = myList.size();
    System.out.println("List Value BEFORE Maximum Size Reached : ");
    System.out.println(myList.toString());

    if (myList.size() >= maxSize) {
        myList.remove(0);
        myList.add("F");
    }

    System.out.println("List Size AFTER Maximum Size Reached : " + listSize);
    System.out.println("List Value AFTER Maximum Size Reached : ");
    System.out.println(myList.toString());
```

And this is the result :

```
List Value BEFORE Maximum Size Reached : 
[A, B, C, D, E]
List Size AFTER Maximum Size Reached : 5
List Value AFTER Maximum Size Reached : 
[B, C, D, E, F]
```